# Firebase Hosting: Needs Setup For Cloudflare DNS

Tags: cloudflare, firebase-hosting

I am trying to set custom domain for my Firebase app.

Firebase hosted url : https://inventory-app-726af.firebaseapp.com/

Custom Domain: **inv.agsft.com**

I have followed all instructions as part of setting custom domain but after verification step when I click on finish button, status will always be "**Needs Setup**".

I am managing DNS through cloudflare (https://www.cloudflare.com/) and I am following Quick setup option.

Any pointers to resolve it?

Comment: When I run `dig -t txt +noall +answer inv.agsft.com` there are no `TXT` records showing. Since those are required to verify your ownership of the domain, Firebase Hosting will not continue the setup beyond step one. Aside from that: there's not enough information here for anyone on Stack Overflow to help. If you want personalized help, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/).

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected TXT record.
dig -t txt +noall +answer inv.agsft.com
inv.agsft.com.  299 IN TXT "google-site-verification=8uObmfAMZrc29piBvbJnRmyKNhONB3Iom6-qMOT9gHk"

Comment: I am trying Advance Setup option, need to wait for 24 hr and I will update details.

Comment: It seems there is something else, I have contacted firebase support and I have not yet received resolution. I will update post with answer after resolution.

Comment: What's the update Pari?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I had the same problem, I was able to resolve it by toggling the DNS Status on cloudflare from `DNS and HTTP Proxy (CDN)` to just `DNS` on the two A records

[image]

It started working right away.

Comment: In this happens to me, how exactly did you do that using Cloudflare's current site?

Comment: @MurraySmith you just click on the cloud on the far right of the row next to each DNS record. So make sure the two A records for your firebase URL is toggled aka it'll show a Grey Cloud.

Comment: So, this disables cloudflare, how I will use it?

Comment: I just tried it and this still works! You only need to do this for the two `firebase1._domainkey` and `firebase2._domainkey` CNAME entries. Which are used to verify your domain ownership. Don't do this for your `www` A records or something similar of course.

Comment: You just need to turn off Cloudflare to prove the ownership of the domain! After it is approved, you can turn it back on! Firebase doesn't see the record you added, if you turn Cloudflare on, as that is the whole purpose of the cloudflare to hide your destination address

Comment: And it is arguable, whether you need Cloudflare at all on top of Firebase hosting

Comment: Thank you, I spent about 30 minutes to understand why it's not working. And you saved me!

Comment: Worked first time for me

Comment: Saved my day and since there is a 15 character min length , you have a good day .

Answer (score 27):

The proper solution, ie without disabling Cloudflare for the site, is to use Full SSL for your domain/subdomain.

You can either choose Full SSL for all your domain entries, or set up a Page Rule for a specific subdomain, in your case, use "inv.agsft.com/*"

Source: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/flexible-ssl-redirect-loop-with-google-firebase/2063/3, which in turn points to https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000219871-Why-does-Flexible-SSL-cause-a-redirect-loop-

Had the same issue and this solved the redirect issue. Firebase will however still report the domain as "Needs setup", for that I have no solution, but it does not affect the functionality of the hosting.

Comment: just changed the option from `Full (Strict)` to `Full` which is more logical if firebase is already providing the SSL certificate

Answer (score 20):

For the people that is using Namecheap, This configuration worked for me.

[image: Namecheap configuration]

Comment: The important change here is to use "@" instead of "mysite.com"

Comment: Using @ doesn't work for me since Cloudflare automatically changes it to mysyte.com

Comment: Yes, this is also the solution for GoDaddy!

Answer (score 9):

To avoid any kind of ssl issues when using **firebase hosting and cloudflare** you have to check to following points:

1. You **don't need** to *toggling the DNS Status on cloudflare from DNS and HTTP Proxy (CDN) to just DNS on the two A records* **unless you don't want the cloudflare ssl certificates and want to just use the firebase ssl certificates** (look to this carefully because you *will loose the protection that cloudflare provides to your site in case you decide to use only the clouflare DNS*)

[image]

If you "keep the cloud orange" it will not causes any problem to your firebase hosting.

2. Add the firebase IP's to cloudflare following the instructions provided by firebase hosting and **remove any other A record from your domain/subdomain that you are setting up**
3. To ensure you have a end-to-end encryption (using **both firebase ssl as well as  cloudflare ssl**), make sure that your cloudflare crypto options is set to "Full":

[image]

4. Use a page rule likes in case that you want your root domain to receive all trafic:

[image]

5. In your firebase hosting setup, do the same:
   [image]

p.s: Look that the message "**Needs setup**" is still there but the app is running without any problem.

p.s2: the majority problems regarding cloudflare and firebase is that firebase ssl can take several hours to start to work and you keep seeing a message like "your connection is not private". It happens not beucase cloudflare is messing our proxy out but because firebase ssl is still not fully propagated.

I hope it help others :)

Answer (score 4):

When I run `dig -t txt +noall +answer inv.agsft.com` there are no TXT records showing. Since those are required to verify your ownership of the domain, Firebase Hosting will not continue the setup beyond step one.

Update: since the next step requires you to map `A` records to the IP addresses of Firebase hosting, I ran the relevant `dig` too:

```
$ dig -t a +noall +answer inv.agsft.com
inv.agsft.com.      299 IN  A   104.18.56.240
inv.agsft.com.      299 IN  A   104.18.57.240
```

Those are not the addresses I'd expect for Firebase Hosting, so it looks like *either* you haven't correctly entered the `A` records, *or* they have't propagated yet.

Comment: I just ran the dig command and got below result.
dig -t txt +noall +answer inv.agsft.com
inv.agsft.com.  299 IN TXT "google-site-verification=8uObmfAMZrc29piBvbJnRmyKNhONB3Iom6-qMOT9gHk"

Comment: Good. But the reason you had the problem you reported above was because the `TXT` records are missing. With that problem fixed, Firebase Hosting should be able to verify that you own the domain (may take up to 24 hours) and then transition to the next phase (adding A records iirc).

Comment: I added some info on what I now see. But since you also filed a support case, I'd recommend updating there, since they can see directly in the support systems what the status is.

Answer (score 4):

**In my case I did the same that Brennen did:**

- toggling the DNS Status on cloudflare from DNS and HTTP Proxy (CDN) to just DNS on the two A records.

**But just start working when I:**

- Delete the domain from firebase. (click on the : points select delete domain)
- refresh the firebase site
- Added again in Quick Setup. I already had the A record added in Cloudflare so I didn't added again.

**After that automatically the status added was connected.**

Remember: Before testing, clean your browser cache.

Answer (score 3):

When I change my setting like below, it started to work again.
Redirect loop fixed:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For GoDaddy this adding the following solved it for me:

TYPE:A

NAME:@

VALUE: your ip_1

TYPE:A

NAME:@

VALUE: your ip_2

Comment: I did this but still displays "Needs setup". Any idea why?

Comment: *solved: I had to remove old 'A's from GoDaddy DNS management.

Comment: @SheikhWahabMahmood 2 domains can be added firebase hosting? not sub domains,, example1.com example2.com and their redirects

Answer (score 2):

**June 2020**

Just wanted to share what was successful for me. It was a combination Brennen and Lisbel's answer.

Step 1: Toggle off your DNS status to get a grey cloud (as shown in the earlier answer)

Step 2: Delete the domain from firebase

Step 3: Add it back with Quick Steup

It should be connected after these steps!

Comment: Did you delete the domain AND redirect domains (http->https) of your website doing this? I have essentially four domains.

Comment: Also when re-added the domains, did you toggle the orange cloud proxy setting on cloudflare or let it be gray?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Here's how I fixed it:

**1)** Cick the View button on the problematic domain (in the Hosting section next to where it says Needs Setup).

**2)** Change the 'Setup mode' from Quick Setup to Advanced and follow the 3 steps

- **2a)** Open your domain provider's settings (I'm using Google Domains) and add the TXT record it's giving you.
- **2b)** Wait about 4-12 hours for verification
- **2c)** Add the provided A records into your domain provider's settings

This is not a quick process, but it should be working about 5 minutes after you complete step 2c.

Answer (score 0):

Toggling DNS mode didn't work for me. So I tried following approach and it worked for me.

1. Add `CNAME` record pointing to `{firebase-project}.firebaseapp.com` or `{firebase-project}.web.app`, you could add `A` record and try.
2. ADD `TXT` record as firebase ask you
3. Verify from firebase (this will show as needs setup, also it didn't go away although this worked)
4. If new domain/subdomain doesn't works check your browser developer tools network tab. If there are lots of 301 happening then go to cloudflare page rules. Add `newdomain.com/*` or `subdomain.newdomain.com/*` then add settings select SSL and set it to full as follows.

[image]

Then it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**Working as of 11st May 2022 without need to toggle DNS and HTTP Proxy (CDN).**

Steps:

1. Go to **Cloudflare Dashboard**.
2. Select **SSL/TLS**.
3. Select **Overview**. [image: Cloudflare SSL/TLS Overview]
4. Select **Full** option for **SSL/TLS encryption mode**.[image]
5. After that, refresh your website that previously have issue to access.
6. Now the website can access successfully.