# Firebase Hosting says, "Needs Setup"

Tags: firebase, ssl, dns, cloudflare, firebase-hosting

I’m having the same issue as described in [Firebase hosting: Needs Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437535/firebase-hosting-needs-setup)

I have a project hosted on firebase and DNS set up via Cloudflare. The domain resolves properly and browsers show the certificates are valid and the connection is secure etc. but, firebase shows status as, “Needs setup”.

I have followed the “Advanced” setup (as described in the URL above) setting both A records and a “.well-known/acme-challenge/[generated filename]” file in place. SSL zone on Cloudflare is set to “Full”. I also set a CNAME record to the Firebase URL as another post suggested. (I did each step over time to try to see which if any fixed the issue or made it worse giving at least 12 hours between.)

Everything seems to work, but firebase still says setup is still required which is ok I guess, but I'm curious about the cause.

Comment: I assume you've waited a while for the DNS to propagate? I've noticed with my projects setup via CloudFlare > Firebase Hosting can take a little while to recognise the DNS changes.

Comment: I see you left 12 hours. Ignore my comment. :)

Comment: Definitely has been long enough now that the DNS must have propagated. I don't understand why Firebase still says, "Needs setup".

Answer (score 2):

In Cloudflare set Proxy Status as DNS only.

[image]

Work for me.